# Math books that generally provide multiple proofs for each lemma

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Most of the math textbooks that I have provide at most a single proof for each result, with some results proven by references to elsewhere in the literature or not proven explicitly and used as exercises instead.

I'm wondering whether there are any books (on any subject within math) that generally provide multiple distinct proofs for given results as a stylistic choice.

Comment: I haven’t seen a book that does this systematically; maybe reading several books simultaneously is a good way to go.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for a really, really long book. I'd second littleO's advice.

Comment: There are resources that provide many proofs for just one result. For example, see https://faculty.umb.edu/gary_zabel/Courses/Phil%20281b/Philosophy%20of%20Magic/Arcana/Neoplatonism/Pythagoras/index.shtml.html for the Pythagorean Theorem. Also, Eisenbud gives many (I think around 5-ish) proofs of the Nullstellensatz in his book on Commutative Algebra. It really just depends.

Comment: I had a certain individual who frequented this site say something rather _tart_ to me about alternative proofs being "unnecessary", but they _can_ often give insight into how the proposition is connected to various other propositions or even other branches of mathematics.  There are places here and there around the 'net for particular important theorems, such as the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra or the "Basel Problem", and so forth.  The "Proofs Without Words" series that Roger Nelsen has been involved with might be of interest; there is also John Dawson's _Why Prove It Again?_ (2015).

Comment: A couple others you might wish to look at are Alsina and Nelsen's _Charming Proofs: A Journey Into Elegant Mathematics_ (which includes many references to the literature for further alternatives) and Aigner and Ziegler's _Proofs From THE BOOK_, currently in its _sixth_ edition (2018), with earlier editions turning up online as .pdfs.

Comment: in my experience many results from combinatorics are well-suited to having multiple proofs. for example my uni's lecture notes take that approach; see [here](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/12699/mod_resource/content/1/Lecture%20notes.pdf), for example